# Forward traffic to VPN

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I have several servers I want to put on a VPN.  I've set the VPN up with OpenVPN and that's working fine, each machine can access the other servers on the VPN.

My issue is I would like to somehow set this up so that say I have two servers inside the VPN like this:

```
+----------------------------------+
|  public ip: 55.66.33.13, eth0    |
|  vpn ip: 10.8.0.8, tun0          |
+----------------------------------+
      Server 1


+----------------------------------+
|  public ip: 55.44.22.11, eth0    |
|  vpn ip: 10.8.0.10, tun0         |
+----------------------------------+
      Server 2
```

I would like to set up a rule with iptables, so that if Server 1 tries to access 54.44.22.11, that traffic would be sent through tun0 to server 2.  So far I've tried:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -d 55.44.22.11 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

and I've tried various forms of `iptables -t nat.....` but that hasn't worked either.

Is there a common name for this?  Even googling this has been a bit troublesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up routing tables on the servers / VPN clients so that these IP addresses are routed via the VPN tunnel.

If you have a single VPN server running, which all clients connect to, you can tell OpenVPN to set up connecting clients' routing tables by adding these lines to OpenVPN server config file:

```
push "route 55.66.33.13 255.255.255.255"
push "route 55.44.22.11 255.255.255.255"
```

Firewall rules work on top of basic routing tables, and can be used to enforce more fine-grained policies than simple routing tables make possible. But, the decision on how to forward traffic is always made first with the routing table entry.

You also need to add `client-to-client` directive to OpenVPN server configuration, which makes it possible for clients to communicate between themselves via the VPN.

Comment: This works great, in that if I ping 55.44.22.11 from 10.8.0.8 (pinging server 2's public address from server 1) I can see that the traffic is being passed to 10.8.0.1, however 10.8.0.1 isn't directing that traffic to 10.8.0.10.  
  
I tried setting up routes on 10.8.0.1 like this:  
    `route add 55.66.33.13 10.8.0.8  
    route add 55.44.22.11 10.8.0.10`  
  
But this doesn't work, and has the odd effect of making it so that even if I try pinging 10.8.0.8 from 10.8.0.10 (which works out the box), it doesn't route.

Comment: See added text in my answer.

Comment: Client-to-client looks like it makes it so that traffic to the 10.8.x.x addresses aren't routed through 10.8.0.1, but when I try to ping one client's public IP address I get these now:   
`From 10.8.0.1: icmp_seq=1 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 10.8.0.1`